# iSCSI over MPIO, Hyper-V Host or Guest

Tags: hyper-v, iscsi

I have a Virtual Machine that needs to have exclusive access to an iSCSI volume. In an all Win Server 2016 / Hyper-V environment is it better to setup iSCSI over MPIO in the Host or in the Guest OS?  Are there any trade offs / issues doing it one way or the other?

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

Comment: I connected the iSCSI volume inside the VM and have not had any issues.  I did however read about an issue with having two iSCSI volumes and having the Host connect them.  iSCSI when connecting more than one volume will sometimes, flip the order in which they are connected.  Vol 1 maybe Disk 2 in Disk management, and sometimes it will be Disk 1.  This messes up the Hypervisor configuration.  FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need "exclusive access" to the iSCSI LUN for your VM you can simply connect iSCSI target inside a VM using built-in Microsoft iSCSI Initiator. If you have more than one channels to connect the iSCSI target you definitely need to install Multipath I/O inside the guest VM and enable iSCSI bus support.